# Assigning applications to specific workspaces

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, workspace

I like keeping different applications on different workspace  like :
 -Work item on one
 -Browser,messengers on one
 -Music , videos on one
( i keep switching between these )
Is there a way to ensure that my applications open in a  specific workspace automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

If you open an app, move it to desired workspace. There click the context menu (usually left top corner) and check "Always on this workspace".

Comment: could you add a screenshot ? I didnot understand your instructions

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gM3vU.png - sorry in Polish, but youll get the idea

Comment: doesnt work in my case :| , tried it with chrome , it shows the option checked in all the workspaces

Comment: Does not work in xubuntu 14