# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity: how to assign applications to specific workspaces?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, window-manager, workspace

I always use my last workspace (workspace 4) for email and instant messaging.
In KDE I could use the window menu (right-click on title bar) to tell KDE to
move new Thunderbird and Pidgin windows to this workspace automatically when
opened.

Apparently, according to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/263151/assigning-applications-to-specific-workspaces), one could do that in Ubuntu 10.04,
too, using the ‘Always on this workspace’ menu item in the window menu.
However, in Ubuntu 12.04 there is no such menu item.

So, my question is this:
How can I make an application open on a specific workspace in Ubuntu 12.04 with
Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [devilspie](http://linux.die.net/man/1/devilspie), preferably with the GUI [gdevilspie](http://code.google.com/p/gdevilspie/).

From [gDevilspie in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/gdevilspie):

> Devils Pie is an application that allows you to run a particular application inside a particular workspace within your GNOME panner in a particular manor.
>
> [...]
>
> gDevils Pie is a graphical front-end for editing the Devils Pie configuration file. gDevils Pie also allows you to stop and start the Devils Pie daemon.

#### Installation

1. Install **gdevilspie** with the suggested add-on **devilspie** from the Software Center or execute the following command in a terminal:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gdevilspie
   ```
2. Open gdevilspie (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, *gdevilspie*, <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
3. Check *Start devilspie daemon automatically at login*.

#### Example

To automatically move a new instance of Thunderbird to workspace 4, do the following:

1. Open gdevilspie and click **Add**.
2. Enter a name (e.g., *Thunderbird*).
3. Check the property **window_name** and enter *Thunderbird* in **contain(s)**.
4. Change to the tab **Actions**.
5. Check the property **Set_workspace** and enter *4* in **workspace**.
6. Click **Save**.
7. Re(start) the daemon by clicking **Stop** (if running), then **Start**.